# Setting an Event handler without doing it manually in the classname.designer.cs file

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Is there any way to set an event handler without doing it manually in the classname.designer.cs file other than double clicking the UI element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Double-click the event you want to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow your question correctly, you can just do it in your code-behind like this:

```
myButton.Click += myHandler;
```

Or you could use an anonymous delegate:

```
myButton.Click += delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use `myControl.Event += new EventHandler(SomeHandlerMethodInYourClass)` somewhere during initialization, e.g. in the form's constructor.